# PROBLEMAS PARA INSERTAR IMAGENES Y VIDEOS EN CKEDITOR 5 LARAVEL 9

Tags: laravel-9, ckeditor

ya me he leído de arriba abajo la documentación de ckeditor5 pero no hay manera de que las funcionales que según indican son gratis, como subir imágenes o videos no terminan de funcionar, el panel de ckeditor esta implementado en el blog tanto en create como en edit para crear los post pero se complica el tema imágenes que es lo que más me interesa. He probado con el CDN pero no funciona, he probado instalando la paquetería por npm, la cuál esta en la carpeta en node-modules, llego al siguiente error a la hora de instalar con el comando npm-install:

- npm install npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency npm WARN
  While resolving: bootstrap-switch@3.3.4 npm WARN Found:
  bootstrap@4.6.2 npm WARN
  node_modules/admin-lte/node_modules/bootstrap npm WARN
  bootstrap@"^4.6.1" from admin-lte@3.2.0 npm WARN
  node_modules/admin-lte npm WARN     admin-lte@"3.2" from the root
  project npm WARN  npm WARN Could not resolve dependency: npm WARN
  peer bootstrap@"^3.1.1" from bootstrap-switch@3.3.4 npm WARN
  node_modules/admin-lte/node_modules/bootstrap-switch npm WARN
  bootstrap-switch@"3.3.4" from admin-lte@3.2.0 npm WARN
  node_modules/admin-lte npm WARN npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency:
  bootstrap@3.4.1 npm WARN node_modules/bootstrap npm WARN   peer
  bootstrap@"^3.1.1" from bootstrap-switch@3.3.4 npm WARN
  node_modules/admin-lte/node_modules/bootstrap-switch npm WARN
  bootstrap-switch@"3.3.4" from admin-lte@3.2.0 npm WARN
  node_modules/admin-lte

El código en la vistas de blade create y edit son estas:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#extract' ) )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#body' ) )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

La consola de ckeditor funciona de manera básica perfectamente pero no logro que la funcionalidad de insertar medios funcione correctemente, he cambiado varias veces el código pero pienso que quizás sea el hecho de estas peer dependencies lo que esta haciendo que esto no funcione de manera básica, ya vi en la documentación que otras funcionalidades son de pago.
Gracias de antemano.